# Block thread until WCF callback is raised?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to wait on a callback in WCF? Given [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks) article, I will raise a callback in my WCF service, but I want the client (a seperate application) to only proceed (ie go to the next line of code, e.g. close a form etc, after the callback is raised. So I need to block until the callback is raised.

How could I do this?

Comment: You're going to have problems if you try to block the UI thread.

Comment: Check out the following link [Synchronization Contexts in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using callbacks, you could call the service synchronously from the client.

If the client does not require any data to be returned, you could return a void, and the client will still wait for the call to complete.